# How to troubleshoot MissingAuthenticationTokenException in the AWS-SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-sdk-go

I'm writing a lambda to rotate secrets in AWS Secret Manager. But I'm getting an error from the SDK when I try to make the call. The code I'm using:

```golang
import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/secretsmanager"
)

func checkSecret(ctx context.Context, secretName string) error {
    awsConfig := aws.NewConfig()
    awsConfig.Region = "us-east-1"
    client := secretsmanager.NewFromConfig(*awsConfig)

    resp, err := client.DescribeSecret(ctx, &secretsmanager.DescribeSecretInput{SecretId: &secretName})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ERR Describing Secret: ", err)
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Invoking this function returns:

```
operation error Secrets Manager: DescribeSecret, 
https response error StatusCode: 400, 
RequestID: b4023b03-6455-41e6-be63-639bff8ec56c, 
api error MissingAuthenticationTokenException: Missing Authentication Token
```

However, if I invoke the same function with AWS CLI it works:

```
> aws secretsmanager describe-secret --secret-id testSecret
{
    "ARN": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:xxxxx:secret:testSecret-eOGWj5",
    "Name": "testSecret",
    "Description": "Test secret to experiment with rotation.",
    "RotationEnabled": true,
    "RotationLambdaARN": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxxxx:function:secretRotator",
    "LastChangedDate": "2022-09-14T16:09:32.485000-05:00",
    "LastAccessedDate": "2022-09-13T19:00:00-05:00",
    "Tags": [],
    "VersionIdsToStages": {
        "0efac0f5-e7d8-4519-8437-0a1c5f302785": [
            "AWSCURRENT"
        ],
        "b7a050c8-69b2-46cd-aba7-7e2927320dad": [
            "AWSPENDING"
        ]
    },
    "CreatedDate": "2022-09-14T15:25:25.246000-05:00"
}
```

So my IAM rules appear correct. I'm running this code locally so that AWS CLI and the code are using the same AWS Credentials.

Googling thus far only turns up troubleshooting around API Gateway for this error.

Comment: Are you using AWS SSO?

Comment: No just an IAM user. Poking more at this, I re-implemented this in AWS SDK v1, and it works. It only fails in v2.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be related to the fact that `aws.NewConfig()` does not load environment variables which may contain the authentication token that is missing.

Please try replacing your code with the following one:

```
import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/secretsmanager"
)

func checkSecret(ctx context.Context, secretName string) error {
    awsConfig := config.LoadDefaultConfig(ctx, config.WithRegion("us-east-1"))
    client := secretsmanager.NewFromConfig(*awsConfig)

    resp, err := client.DescribeSecret(ctx, &secretsmanager.DescribeSecretInput{SecretId: &secretName})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ERR Describing Secret: ", err)
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```